# Installing mongodb, to use mongoimport, on 3.7-slim-buster image

Tags: docker, debian

This is for an Airflow project, and we're starting with [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/Dockerfile), which itself seems to start with the `debian:buster-slim` image.

[This post](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-mongodb-on-debian-10/) suggested to run the following:

```
sudo apt install dirmngr gnupg apt-transport-https software-properties-common ca-certificates curl
curl -fsSL https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/4.2 main'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mongodb-org
```

however when we add `RUN apt install dirmngr gnupg apt-transport-https software-properties-common ca-certificates curl` to the Dockerfile, we get the errors:

```
E: Unable to locate package dirmngr
E: Package 'gnupg' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package software-properties-common
```

What should we add to this Dockerfile in order to properly install mongodb to be able to use `mongoimport` command?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the following is doing the trick:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg software-properties-common
RUN curl -fsSL https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | apt-key add -
RUN add-apt-repository 'deb https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/4.2 main'
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-org

RUN mongo --version
RUN mongoimport --version
```

Last 2 lines to test that the first 5 lines worked. Initially ran into issues installing `gnupg` and `software-properties-common` but the `-y` flag and the `apt-get update` beforehand helped. Everything seems good so far with this.